Three integers are chosen at random without replacement from the first 20 integers. The probability that their product is even is:
we know that probability of a certain event = $\frac{number\ of\ favorable\ cases}{\operatorname{total}\ number\ of\ cases}$
Here the total number of cases is obviously C(20,3)=1140 .And According to my logic and understanding for the product of three numbers to be even any one of the number can be an even number. SO from that logic we got 10 even numbers and 10 odd numbers within the set of first 20 integers. So, Shouldn't the total favorable case be $\frac{10\cdot18\cdot19}{3!}=570$.
The 10 for the choices of 10 even numbers and 19 as the question suggests without replacement and 18 for the choices for the 3rd number and divided by 3! in order that the arrangement doesn't matter so from this we should conclude the probability to be $\frac{570}{1140}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$
From my own research to the question this answer seems to wrong and the probability seems to exceed the number 0.5. If so, What is wrong with my logic and what should be added to my logic.

The number of unfavorable cases is clearly $\binom {10}3=120$ as these are the cases in which you choose $3$ odd numbers.  I can't follow your computation.

Oh, I guess you are saying something like "fix an even selection and then choose the other two at random" but that doesn't make sense since you count selections with multiple even numbers several times.  Though why you divide by $3!$ eludes me.   If, as it appears, you are requiring the first choice to be even (for the numerator) then I'd have thought that you would want to multiply by $3!$ but, as I say, the approach is flawed from the start.

You are insisting that the first number be even, but if you choose $1,5,2$ the product is $10$
